# Embed Power BI to webpage

Tags: .net-core, iframe, powerbi

I have published a Power BI model and would like to embed it to my website.

One working solution is to embed as an `iframe`, this works fine.

The problem arised, when access to the Power BI model, which is in the local Report Server, was restricted only to the IP of my server. That's to say, if it's requested from the backend, it would be reachable. But if it's called in the frontend (like in iframe), it would fail, as user IP is different.

As I understood, solution would be to call the Power BI model in the backend and send html code to the frontend.

Am I right? What would be the best solution?

Comment: This wont work. Power BI is interactive tool and uses a lot of client code, so you can't "just send html code".

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Is there another solution?

Comment: No one can give a solution to a problem, which is not clear. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Would you be so kind to suggest, what is unclear?